# How to change line width of a column in table?

Tags: tables

How to change line width of a column in table? I colored the table and some column lines aren't appearing, It's so tight that only with zoom it appears

```
\definecolor{cNaoImplementado}{rgb}{0.80,0.80,0.80}
\definecolor{cImplementado}{rgb}{0,0.8,0} 
    ...
\begin{landscape}
    \chapter{Product Backlog}
        % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Plan1'
        \begin{longtable}{|p{0.5in}|p{6in}|c|c|}

        \hline
          {\bf ID} & {\bf Users Stories} & {\bf Tempo Previsto} & {\bf Status} \\

        \hline \rowcolor{cImplementado}
                 1 & Como professor, eu quero decidir quais compromissos são públicos ou privados para manter sigilo. &         10 & Implementado \\

        \hline \rowcolor{cImplementado}
                 2 & Como professor, eu quero a partir de uma disciplina cadastrar um plano de ensino com o programa e as bibliografias suplementares para as disciplinas que eu vou ministrar. &         40 & Implementado \\

        \hline \rowcolor{cImplementado}
                 3 & Como professor, eu quero cadastrar meus compromissos no sistema para que todos saibam quando não posso agendar outro compromisso. &         40 & Implementado \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}          
\end{landscape}
```

[image]

Comment: For a global line width modification, `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}` works.

Comment: Can we see a minimal document with a simple table showing the way you apply color and the problematic lines?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I just updated with an example

Comment: @Rafael perhaps it's just a viewer issue?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Well I guess so, I tested it on texStudio viewer and viewing generated PDF